# Python Classes Clarification - Python Crash Course Book

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm currently working through Python Crash Course, I'm on chapter 9 - Classes. I am confused about some things and need clarification.  There is a long setup to my questions, but I am trying to be thorough.

9-7: Admin

"An administrator is a special kind of user. Write a class called Admin that inherits from the User class you wrote in Exercise 9-3 (page 166) or Exercise 9-5 (page 171). Add an attribute, privileges, that stores a list of strings like "can add post", "can delete post", "can ban user", and so on. WRite a method called show_privileges() that lists the administrator’s set of privileges. Create an instance of Admin, and call your method."

I solved 9-7 with this code:

```
class Admin(User):
    def __init__ (self, first_name, last_name):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name) 
        self.privileges = []
        #For 9-8 the above lines changes to
        #self.privileges = Privileges() 

    def show_privileges(self):
        if self.privileges:
            print("The admins privileges are")
            for privilege in self.privileges:
                print(privilege)
        else:
            print("There are no privileges set for this admin")

user1 = Admin("Foo", "Bar")

user1.show_privileges()
user1.privileges = [
    'can add users ',
    'can ban users ',
    'can delete users ',
    ]
user1.show_privileges()
```

Moving on...

9-8 Privileges

"Write a separate Privileges class. The class should have one attribute, privileges, that stores a list of strings as described in Exercise 9-7. Move the show_privileges() method to this class. Make a Privileges instance as an attribute in the Admin class. Create a new instance of Admin and use your method to show its privileges."

I solved 9-8 with this code:

Admittedly a little help from the authors solution on github.

```
class Privileges():
    #A seperate privileges class
```

Below, I had to set a privileges parameter equal to an empty list after self but in 9.7 this was done under **init**.  Why the need for the change?

```
    def __init__(self, privileges=[]):
    #Initialize self and privileges
        self.privileges = privileges
```

Why the need for the change?

```
    def show_privileges(self):
    #A method to print the privileges of an admin
        if self.privileges:
            print("The admins privileges are")
            for privilege in self.privileges:
                print(privilege)
        else:
            print("There are no privileges set for this admin")


user1 = Admin('foo', 'bar')
user1.describe_user()

user1.privileges.show_privileges()
```

Below, I had to set the list equal to a variable, whereas in the 9-7 problem this wasn't necessary.

```
user1_privileges = [
    "I do it all",
    "Yes I do that that too"
    ]
```

Below, why is there a need for two .privileges here, when in 9-7 I only had to use one when setting it directly.

```
user1.privileges.privileges = user1_privileges
user1.privileges.show_privileges()
```

What exactly is **init** and what determines its parameters?

I figured I could approach this problem in a similar manor to 9-7 and I don't see the need for the changes described above.  I appreciate it if you could clarify this for me.